# Position to be increased automatically in Position Column in Catalog > Manage Categories > Category Products

Tags: product, category, position

In Catalog > Manage Categories > Category Products,  I want to randomly order Product position. It is fine for me to edit product position manually if total number of products for Specific category is up to 20 or 30. It is not ok for me if total no of products is 50+. From the side of marketing, sometimes, they want to order products randomly but not by product ID.

As a default in the Position Column of Category Products tab, all products position is set as 1. I don't want 1. What I want is when I add Product A under Category 1, I want its position to be 1. When I add Product B under the same category, I want its position to be 2. For the Product C, I want its position to be 3 and so so. Anyone can help me please? Thank you so much.